# Negative SEO effect on creative h1 full of span classes: Yes or no?

Tags: html, css, seo

I've had a look around and couldn't find much on the topic of "creative" h1 tags and only a little on span classes within the h1 tag.

I've designed an h1 as an equation, see on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/pascalgarrix/pen/QWBOBLV)
Any idea what the impact on SEO can be with something like this instead of a more conservative h1?

Thanks!

```css
h1 { font-size: calc(1rem); }

.equation, .fraction {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

.fraction span, .equation span { display: block; }
.equation > span { font-size: 70%; margin-top: -0.5ex; }
.fraction { margin-bottom: 0.3ex; }
.numerator { margin-top: 0.3ex; }
.fraction .divider { display: none; }
.denominator { border-top: 4px solid black; }
.fraction sup, .fraction sub { font-weight: 200; }
```

```html
<h1>
  <span class="equation">
    <span class="lim">YOUR</span> <span class="lim">VISION</span>
  </span>

  &#10005;
  <!-- 'X' -->

  <span class="fraction">
    <span class="numerator">(WEB DESIGN + Development) <sup>A/B testing</sup></span>
  <span class="divider">/</span>
  <span class="denominator"><sub>Research based</sub> UI + UX Design</span>
  </span>

  &equals;

  <span class="equation">
    <span class="lim">AWARD</span>
  <span class="lim">WINNING</span>
  <span class="lim">AGENCY</span>
  </span>
</h1>
```

Comment: Where is there so much in the H1?

Answer (score 0):

**the better way is that:**

take a normale Headline => <h1
then make a normale Description Text in <p
And then make your code example in normal div/span etc...

Answer (score 0):

As long as Google can read the content cleanly, this should not be a problem. Take a look at the Google cache. But the question is, what are you hoping to get out of it? More SEO power? It's already cool implemented. Try it out.